# Semantic warning for property whose type is more specific that the one defined in superclass

Tags: objective-c

I'm fairly new to Objective-C, and this is my first question on StackOverflow. Please pardon me in advance if I am missing something obvious.

I'm getting a compiler warning

```
"Semantic Issue: Property type 'B *' is incompatible with type 'A *' inherited from 'X'"
```

The code still compiles and works as expected. I want to know if I should be doing something different to remove the compiler warning.

I have four classes defined as follows:

---

```
//
// *** In class header file A.h

#import "X.h"

@interface A
@property X *variable1;
@end
```

---

```
//
// *** In class B header file B.h

#import "Y.h"

@interface B : A          // B is a subclass of A
@property Y *variable1;   // More specific type for property defined in superclass
@end
```

---

```
//
// *** In class X header file X.h

@class A;                  // Forward declaration to avoid circular imports

@interface X
@property A *variable2;
@end
```

---

```
//
// *** In class Y header file Y.h

@class B;                  // Forward declaration to avoid circular imports

@interface Y : X           // Y is a subclass of X
@property B *variable2;    // More specific type <-- I'm getting the compiler warning here
@end
```

---

I'm getting the compiler warning in the property declaration of variable2 in class Y. I've defined this property as type B, which is a subclass of A. This property is defined as type A in the superclass.

If I #import "B.h" in class Y's header instead of the forward declaration, the compiler sees that B is a subclass of A and the warning disappears. However, I get into an #import loop because class B's header file also #imports "Y.h". I've therefore put in the forward declarations to make the code compile, but I now get this compiler warning.

Despite the warning, the code still works as I expected. I'm wondering if there is a proper way to do this so that I don't get the warning. Any help or insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The definitions of `A` and `B` alone are dangerous. I can say `B *b = [B new]; A *a = b; a.variable1 = [X new]; doSomethingWithY(b.variable1);`. The expression `b.variable1` is typed as a `Y*` but it will actually return an `X*`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Kevin. I didn't think of the scenario you just mentioned. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Objective-C is duck-typed, this isn't as serious an issue as it would be in another language, but, basically, if someone creates an object of your B subclass and passes it to code that expects the A superclass, that code might set the property with an X instead of a Y.  This would leave the wrong class of object in the property, and subsequent uses of the object, expecting a Y, might malfunction when they fetch an X instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Hot Licks. I believe you are pointing out the same flaw as Kevin did in his comment. I didn't think of this possible scenario. (I tried to upvote your answer but it looks like I need to build up some more reputation before I can do that...) Thanks again.